# negative margins and overlapping divs

Tags: html, css, margin

I played around with negative margins and  I know a solution for my problem, but why does the sidebar div overlaps the sidebar-header div? I want to understand the behavior of css in this case.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/sjpqv

Comment: Because you have negative left margin on the sidebar. Try your code starting with no negative margin, then add it only to the header. You can see the entire header + sidebar shifts left. so if you add another -350 to the sidebar then of course it will overlap.

Comment: And what is the question?? that's what negative margin does

Comment: I don't understand the question, this "is" what margins do. Your question is tantamount to asking why does pizza taste like pizza.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When floating left the two div elements, each one will be positioned on the left, side by side. Their order is based on the order entered in html.

They are both inside a div with class name `container` that has a left margin of 350px, this means that its contents (the two floating divs) will be moved 350px from the left side.

Then on the first div `.sidebar-header` you enter a negative left margin of 350px, this results in moving this div to the left back where it was initialy on the very left side of the document. This also causes the second floating div `.sidebar` to stay on its side. The first floating div `.sidebar-header` has a width of 330px. So the second div is 330px from the left side, as it remains on the side of the first div.

When you place negative left margin of 350px to the second div, then you move it to the very left side of the document as well, since it was only 330px away, overlapping with the first div. If for example the first div, `.sidebar-header`,  had width larger than 350px then they would eventually not overlap.

Comment: So every floated element with an negative margin stops following the internal order?